# /DEBUG:FASTLINK в visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, компиляция

При компиляции проекта в `visual studio` выдаётся следующая ошибка:

```
не удалось найти Debug/Source.obj, сборка была выполнена с /DEBUG:FASTLINK
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Та же @@@@@ когда-то была, есть два выхода: первый - скопировать код и вставить в новый проект - это для маленьких проектов. Второй - остановить компиляцию, убедится что нужный проект лежит в DEBUG-папке, исправить ошибку в коде, можно просто убрать кусок с ошибкой и пере компилировать проект.